# Importing excel spreadsheet in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, excel, import-from-excel

I have a question regarding importing( Via the import/export wizard) an excel spreadsheet into sql server 2000.

Everything seems to run fine, no errors etc, but when I select the data from my table, I've noticed that it skiped the first row.  I thought maybe there was a "1st row is Data headers" flag , but I can't seem to find anything like that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Enterprise Manager with no Luck.  I tried Microsfot SQl Server Management Studio and it worked fine.  Studio had an option  (first row is column headers) that Enterprise manager didn't.